Group calendar is no longer automatically adding invitations sent to its email address
I have a Google Calendar, with a calendar ID of

xyz@group.calendar.google.com

It's set to auto-accept invitations:

It's also set to notifications on new events:

However, this stopped working recently: my friend sends me invitations to my xyz@group.calendar.google.com address, and it is:

neither showing up in the calendar
nor sending notification of the new event (IMHO because there is no new event at all)
nor sending a notification for accepting this invitation.

How could I debug this problem? Or what else worth checking?

Can you confirm that "I have a Google Calendar" should actually read "I am part of a Family group and we have a Google calendar"  If that is the case, then see this question Send invite to Google family calendar from Outlook.  If it isn't, please [edit] your question to include more detail about the type of calendar.
